# Writing a Method findString to find a single instance of a character

Tags: java, string, while-loop, char

I have to write a method with the following prompt.
"Write the method findString. This method will take a string of length 1 to find in the line,
at a given starting point. It will return the location of the goal string. This differs from the indexOf method of the String class because it requires the string be just a single instance of the string, so if the string appears two or more times consecutively, it will not return any of those values. If there is no single instance, the method should return -1. Consider the following examples, where line has the value "aabaccb"."

This is what I have:

```
public int findString(String str, int start)
{ 
    int x = line.indexOf(str, start);
    int length = line.length()-1;
    int z = 0;

    if (x > -1 && (x == length || (line.charAt(x) != line.charAt(x + 1))))
    { 
        return x;
    }

    if(x > -1 && (line.charAt(x) == line.charAt(x + 1)))
    { 
        while (x > -1 && line.charAt(x) == line.charAt(x + 1))
        { 
            line = line.substring(x+2);
            z+= 3;
            x = line.indexOf(str);
        }
        return x+z;
    }
    else
    { 
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I've been stuck on this method for a long time, as my knowledge of java is limited. Any help at all would be appreciated. I don't know how I would begin to account for if str occurs more than twice in a row.

Comment: Can you give an input/output example?

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to find the position of a given character that is not preceded or followed by the same character.

That just means you keep searching if you find a character that is not "alone".

Here is an example implementation that deviates from your method signature to be easier to test:

```
private static int findString(String line, char ch, int start) {
    int idx = line.indexOf(ch, start);
    while (idx != -1 && ((idx > 0 && line.charAt(idx - 1) == ch) ||
                         (idx < line.length() - 1 && line.charAt(idx + 1) == ch)))
        idx = line.indexOf(ch, idx + 1);
    return idx;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(findString("aabaccb", 'a', 0)); // prints: 3
System.out.println(findString("aabaccb", 'b', 0)); // prints: 2
System.out.println(findString("aabaccb", 'c', 0)); // prints: -1
System.out.println(findString("aabaccb", 'a', 5)); // prints: -1
System.out.println(findString("aabaccb", 'b', 5)); // prints: 6
System.out.println(findString("aabaccb", 'c', 5)); // prints: -1
```

Notice how the last one still rejects `c` even though it started the search at the last `c`. Just because search starts at the last character of a sequence, doesn't mean the character is suddenly "alone".